# draw more than one plot using vba

Tags: excel, draw, vba

I am trying to draw more than one plot using vba in excel I wrote this code which enable me to draw one drawing

```
Sub trial()
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.HasLegend = True
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""HBES"""
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=EN!$G$253:$G$257"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "=EN!$dp$253:$dp$257"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Name = "=""NHBES"""
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).XValues = "=EN!$G$253:$G$257"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = "='EN1'!$do$253:$do$257"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Name = "=""NHBCS"""
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).XValues = "=EN!$G$253:$G$257"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Values = "=EN1c!$do$253:$do$257"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).Name = "=""HBCS"""
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).XValues = "=EN!$G$253:$G$257"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).Values = "=ENC!$dp$253:$dp$257"
    With ActiveChart
     'chart name
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Expected Number of goods for Group Twenty in Condition State Five"
     'X axis name
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Time (Years)"
     'y-axis name
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Expected Number of goods"
End With
End Sub
```

What I need to do is to make the data range variable I tried to adjust the above code in the following manner

```
 Sub trial()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers).Select
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        ActiveChart.HasLegend = True
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""HBES"""
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=EN!$G$253:$G$257"
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = Sheets("Sheets12").Range(Cells(253,32),Cells(302,32))
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Name = "=""NHBES"""
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).XValues = "=EN!$G$253:$G$257"
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = Sheets("Sheets13").Range(Cells(253,32),Cells(302,32))
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Name = "=""NHBCS"""
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).XValues = "=EN!$G$253:$G$257"
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Values = Sheets("Sheets14").Range(Cells(253,32),Cells(302,32))
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).Name = "=""HBCS"""
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).XValues = "=EN!$G$253:$G$257"
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).Values = Sheets("Sheets15").Range(Cells(253,32),Cells(302,32))
        With ActiveChart
         'chart name
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Expected Number of goods for Group Twenty in Condition State Five"
         'X axis name
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Time (Years)"
         'y-axis name
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Expected Number of goods"
    End With
    End Sub
```

but it doesn't work Any suggestion please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `Sheets("Sheets12")`, `Sheets("Sheets13")` etc. seem odd, in the first snippet the address refers to a sheet called `EN` `'EN1'` while in the second snippet you're referring to a sheet actually called "Sheets12", "Sheets13".

Comment: I tried Sheets("EN") etc.... also I try to put WorkSheets("EN or Sheets12") etc... but it doesn't work. I don't know what to do next and why it doesn't work

Comment: What is the actual name of the sheet, as it appears in the tab below the sheet?

Comment: sheet 12 is written as EN

Comment: You are amazing man its work fine thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the first series you're trying to add. In the first snippet you're trying to pull the data from the Range `DP253:DP257`, the columnindex for column `DP` is `120`, not `32` `Cells(253, 32)` refers to cell `AF253` and `Cells(302, 32)` refers to cell `AF302`.

For the plot named "HBES"

```
.Values = Sheets("EN").Range(Cells(253, 120), Cells(257, 120))
```

---

### Edit

For the plot named "NHBES"

```
.Values = Sheets("'EN1'").Range(Cells(253, 119), Cells(257, 119))
```

For the plot named "NHBCS"

```
.Values = Sheets("EN1c").Range(Cells(253, 119), Cells(257, 119))
```

For the plot named "HBCS"

```
.Values = Sheets("ENC").Range(Cells(253, 120), Cells(257, 120))
```

The code is built up as follows

```
Sheets("NAME OF THE SHEET AS IT APPEARS ON THE TAB IN YOUR WORKBOOK").Range(Cells(ROWNUMBER of the top (left) cell in the range, COLUMNNumber of the top (left) cell in the range), Cells(ROWNUMBER of the bottom (right) cell in the range, COLUMNUMBER of the bottom right cell in the range))
```

If you are referring to range A1:B5, you'd type `Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(5, 2)`

Comment: it doesn't work the program can only recoginize the the first sheet and I have error when it try to read data from other sheets

Comment: What are the exact names of the sheets you're trying to get the data from, the 13th, 14th and 15th sheet. and what is the code you currently have at lines `FullSeriesCollection(2).Values`. `FullSeriesCollection(3).Values`, and `FullSeriesCollection(4).Values`?

Comment: the same as the code before with the adjustment that you recommend the code stop at this line Sheets("Sheets13").Range(Cells(253,32),Cells(302,32)) and give me error

Comment: it doesn't work the code stop st this line .Values = Sheets("'EN1'").Range(Cells(253, 119), Cells(257, 119))

Comment: That's where I need a bit of information from your end, I made the assumption based on the first code snippet that the name of the the 13th sheet is 'EN1' including the the ' (apostrophes) but it is likely that I made the wrong assumption.